# Windows7でnpm installするとエラーになる

Tags: node.js, npm

windows7でnpm installするとエラーが発生します
`C:\Users\username\package.json`が存在していないというエラーのようです
どうすれば解決できるのでしょうか?

node5.9.0
npm3.7.3
を使っています

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\package.json'
npm WARN username No description
npm WARN username No repository field.
npm WARN username No README data
npm WARN username No license field.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npm install` は、カレントディレクトリにある package.json に書かれた全パッケージを、同カレントディレクトリの node_modules/ ディレクトリにインスールするコマンドです。よって package.json が存在しない場合には、動作の前提条件を満たせないためそのようなエラーになります。もしも本当に `npm install` を実行したいのであれば、package.json が存在するディレクトリに `cd` で移動した上で `npm install` してください。

特定のパッケージをカレントディレクトリの node_modules/ ディレクトリへインストールしたいのであれば、 `npm install foobar` のようにパッケージ名を指定して実行する必要があります。またカレントディレクトリではなくグローバルにインストールしたい場合 `npm install -g foobar` のように、`-g` オプションを付けて実行してください。